# BIDS 2008: Filtering based on the value of a parameter

Tags: sql, expression, bids

I'm trying to filter a table based on the value of Parameter and the values for a field.

I'm using `FailedFlag` which is a field which contains only `Yes` and `No` values.

And i'm using a parameter called `Filter` with `Failed Only` and `All`.

Currently i'm using this expression in the tables filter value expression,

```
=IIF(Parameters!Filter.Value = "Failed Only","Yes", "Yes" OR "No")
```

The first bit works, when `filter` is set to `Failed Only` the table only shows rows where the `FailedFlag` is `Yes` however the second part of the expression where the `Filter` parameter is NOT `Failed Only` doesn't return any rows.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

I think your syntax is wrong.  `IIF` has the form

```
IIF(<expression_to_evaluate>,<value_if_true>,<value_if_false>)
```

When I try to evaluate `"Yes" OR "No"`, I get an error.  I don't think you can do a logical Or on strings.  In the false case, it probably ignores the error expression so it doesn't have a value to use for filtering.

In your table Filters, set this as the expression

```
=IIF(Parameters!Filter.Value "Failed Only", "Yes", "No")
```

Set the operator dropdown box to `=`, and in the value box put `=Fields!FailedFlag.Value`

Hopefully [this screenshot](http://imgur.com/PqtvZnq) clarifies.